# Merging raster elevation data

Tags: qgis, raster, merge, elevation, mosaic

Using QGIS I have to merge 416 raster files with elevation data, at the beginning I´m using with only 4 of them to try out:

- When using "merge" (Raster > Miscellaneous) the result are a file with only black and white which have not included all the raster files i selected.
- With "build virtual raster" (Raster > Miscellaneous) I get the merged file but with a different colour scale. I don´t know if it would affect further analysis.
- And with the SAGA tool "Mosaic raster layers" the grid file could not be generated.

I have tried modifying some options without success.

How do I maintain the colour scale when using "build virtual raster"?

Comment: What format are your rasters in? Could you share a sample? Maybe is only happening on your machine.

Comment: Rasters are in TIF format, I have solve the problem. "Build virtual raster" worked when I loaded all 416 file in the layers panel. Before I only selected the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Build virtual raster" worked when I loaded all the files in the layers panel. Before I just selected the directory in the "build virtual raster" window, and it didn´t worked. For the last I save the new VRT file as a raster layer.